# Is it possible to access children of $location variables in Firebase rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Having this data structure:

```
users:{
    AYhiJQchwKSwG5p0epd1GrZAQMg2: {
      savedPhotos:{
        21142:true
        123:true
      }
      .
      .
    }
photos:{
    0:{
      id:9213
      install_count:4
    }
    .
    .
 }
```

I would like to restrict users to save a photo more than once.
Something like this:
...

```
"install_count":{
          ".write":"root.child('users/'+auth.uid).exists()" ,
          ".validate":"root.child('users/savedPhotos'+$photo.id).exists()"
        }
```

...

Comment: You're missing a `/` in `root.child('users/savedPhotos'+$photo.id)` after `savedPhotos`.

Comment: That line of code was just to show what I am looking for. The problem is that  I can't access the id key from $photo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply...
it should be something like this :

```
"photos": {
    ".write": {
        ".validate":"root.child('users/savedPhotos/'+newData.child('id')).exists()"
    }
}
```

If I may suggest... 
You should avoid :
 - using numbers as keys (you may not have the guarantee of their uniqueness), 
 - saving arrays directly (please check this old link but still valid AFAIK https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html ).

-- Edit --

If you wanted to validate the writing of the install_count only:

```
"photos": {
    "$index": {
        "install_count": {
            ".validate":"root.child('users/savedPhotos/'+newData.parent().child('id')).exists()" 
        }
    }
}
```

Ref:
firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#newdata
firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#parent